USB not recognized if formatted as "Master Boot Record - W95 FAT32 (LBA)"
When I insert the USB, it does not appear in the devices list in Files.
Its properties are, as per Disks App:

model: USB Disk 3.0 (1100)
device: /dev/sda1
partitioning: Master Boot Record
partition type: W95 FAT32 (LBA)
content: unknown

I need to read it in order to put in in my Wii games.
Years ago I used qwbfsmanager but it is no more available (I already tried on Windows 10 Pro but with more issues...).
I already installed wiithon but at launch it does nothing, if I launch it from terminal this output occurs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/games/wiithon", line 138, in <module>
    App()
  File "/usr/games/wiithon", line 48, in App
    prefs.cargarPreferenciasPorDefecto()
  File "/usr/share/wiithon/preferencias.py", line 53, in cargarPreferenciasPorDefecto
    self.iniciarPreferencia('string', 'device_seleccionado')
  File "/usr/share/wiithon/preferencias.py", line 283, in iniciarPreferencia
    preferencia = session.query(Preferencia).filter(sql).first()
  File "<string>", line 2, in filter
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 220, in generate
    fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1789, in filter
    criterion = expression._expression_literal_as_text(criterion)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 4556, in _expression_literal_as_text
    return _literal_as_text(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 4579, in _literal_as_text
    return _literal_as(element, _no_text_coercion)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 4565, in _literal_as
    return text_fallback(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 4609, in _no_text_coercion
    "extra": "%s " % extra if extra else "",
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Textual SQL expression u"preferencias.campo=='devi..." should be explicitly declared as text(u"preferencias.campo=='devi...")

There is a way to read it or a program to handle Wii (wbfs) files on Ubuntu?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 (on different machines) and unfortunately I cannot upgrade to the latest one.
Thanks

@guiverc I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 but I cannot update to a newer version because some app I use will not be anymore available. I hope in some help even if I'm using a EOL version...)

@guiverc I use them on different machines

You can analyze the problem according to this link and if you are lucky, find a solution. - When you can see the device, then you need to mount the filesystem, which can be difficult if it is 'dirty'. This link may be helpful to make it possible to mount it and read its files by Ubuntu.
